# Intersystems Cache ODBC & PHP Character Encoding

Tags: php, caching, utf-8, odbc, intersystems

Our billing software at work uses Intersystems Cache database to store all relevant data. I am currently developing a web based (PHP) application that displays various metrics based on this data.

When viewing some of the data random strings contain illegal characters in a number of columns from various tables. This is only an issue when that data is passed to PHP. If I dump directly from the database to a file everything looks great.

[Example String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rHRj.gif)

I assume this is due to a charset\encoding problem.
I am almost certain that the data returned from Cache is UTF-8.
I have tried using HTML meta tags, Apache Charset flags, and iconv and I am unable to get these strings to display properly.

If anyone can provide some suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Essential Info:
Server: Ubuntu Server 10.04
Apache: 2.2.14
PHP: 5.3.2
InterSystems Cache: 2008.2.2
InterSystems Cache ODBC Driver: 2008.2.4

Thanks 
Mike

Comment: Is the column name larger than 31 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's causing the problem as I'm not a Cache ODBC expert. However, you could always try using the M/Gateway MGWSI gateway with its m_php adapter as an alternative to ODBC.  See:

http://gradvs1.mgateway.com/main/index.html?path=mgwsiMenu

Rob